# Use mongodb types definitions in my own definitions file

Tags: mongodb, import, typescript

I have a problem with TypeScript imports :

Here is my **mydef.d.ts**:

```
import * as mongodb from "mongodb";
interface UserDto {
    _id: mongodb.ObjectID;
    username: string;
}
```

And here is my **main.ts**:

```
import * as mongodb from "mongodb";
let user: UserDto = {
    _id: new mongodb.ObjectID("anyID"),
    username: "Xstoudi"
}
```

But in main.ts: `Cannot find name UserDto`.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to **export** your interface in **mydef.d.ts**.

```js
import * as mongodb from "mongodb";
export interface UserDto {
    _id: mongodb.ObjectID;
    username: string;
}
```

Then you need to **import** it in **main.ts**, the same way you import mongo.

```js
import * as mongodb from "mongodb";
import {UserDto} from "mydef";
let user: UserDto = {
    _id: new mongodb.ObjectID("anyID"),
    username: "Xstoudi"
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I did not suspected I can import something from a def file !